# How do I tell if the matrix is invertible by seeing if the columns form a basis of R^5?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}3&1&4&1&5&9\\2&6&5&3&5&8\\9&7&9&3&2&3\\8&4&6&2&6&4\\3&3&8&3&2&7\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Do the columns of $A$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$?

And based on that, is the matrix A invertible?

This is the rref.

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&-23/11\\0&1&0&0&0&4/3\\0&0&1&0&0&106/33\\0&0&0&1&0&-214/33\\0&0&0&0&1&50/33\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: A non-square matrix can't be invertible...

Comment: @Jo Mo The concept of invertible matrix is only defined for square matrices. Note that $A$ is $5\times 6$.

Comment: You clearly do not know any of the definitions that appear on your "question"!

Comment: The columns of your matrix *span* $\mathbb{R}^5$, but they cannot be linearly independent.  (The first $5$ of them do form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$, though.)

Comment: Any basis of $\mathbf{R}^5$ has exactly $5$ vectors.  Your matrix has $6$ columns.

Comment: Just an irrelevant observation. The rows appended gives the first $25$ digits of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, your actual question has been if $AA^T$ is invertible or not. $AA^T$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix. Then, you can find if it is invertible or not, by seeing if your original matrix is full row-lank. And since, row and column rank are equal, you can find it out, by verifying if your column rank here is $5$ or less. Or equivalently, if columns make a basis for $\mathbb{R}^5.$ I should add that $rank(AA^T)=rank(A)$.